# symfony 2 redirect if user is logged in and wants to call /login

Tags: php, symfony

I've the following problem in my symfony 2 application.

When a user is already is logged in he still has access to the route /login.
What is the best way to avoid this case ?

I tried to redirect the user if he wants to login, but this didn't works, as i thought.

```
public function loginAction()
{
   if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
       // not logged in
       ...
       code
       ...
       ..
       .
    } else {
        // already logged in 
        $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('HereIsMyRouteName'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it on my own, the problem was that I have to return the redirect.

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('HereIsMyRouteName'));
```